# Request.Form empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-post

i have a aspx form

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">   
<div>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="362px">
        <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" CellPadding="5">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="UserName :"></asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="userName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </asp:TableCell>
            ----- SOME CODE HERE---
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" style="height: 29px" />
    </asp:Panel>
</form>
```

I want to post the values from this form to a different page on the click event. 
click event code is :

```
   protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Response.Redirect(ccpUrl);


    }
```

when i do a Request.form on the landing page it is EMPTY.it throws null reference exception.
here is the code for that

```
 private void GetRequestData()
    {

            _userName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["userName"].ToString();
            _password = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["password"].ToString();
            _transactionID = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["transactionID"].ToString();
            if (Request.Form["sequenceNumber"] != null)
            {
                int.TryParse((HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["sequenceNumber"].ToString()), out _sequenceNumber);
            }
            else
                _sequenceNumber = 0;
            _tpsSystem = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["tpsSystem"].ToString();


    }
```

what am i doing wrong ?
Am i missing something ? please help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Response.Redirect()` only redirects the page. It doesn't forward any header information whatsoever. You'll need to set up a cross-page PostBack.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139(v=vs.140).aspx
or
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/604553/Postback-and-Cross-Page-Posting-in-ASP-NET

Should give you some guidance.

Or you can set up the button like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Login" PostBackUrl="/page2.aspx" style="height: 29px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ClientIDMode="static"`. You're field names are being dynamically generated, and will not match those you have put in the ID fields.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="userName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

You should also do the redirect with `Server.Transfer` to ensure the values are transferred to the subsequent page you are redirecting to. `Request.Form[...]` returns null when a key is not found, and the `ToString()` on that value will give you a `NullReferenceException` (since you cannot invoke a method on a null value).

Comment: it still throws NullReferenceException and the form object is empty {}

Comment: Did you use Server.Transfer rather than Response.Redirect?